# custom route .net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to wrap my head around some custom routing but I'm getting 404s when I try to access my site.

I've tried both of these in my global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Show",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{trip}/{year}/{user}",
        defaults :new  { controller = "Home", action = "Show" }
        );
}
```

and

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{trip}/{year}/{user}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Show", trip = "", year = "", user = "" }
        );
}
```

here is the controller action method:

```
public ActionResult Show(string trip, string year, string user)
{
    ViewBag.imagepath = "/Uploadedimages/" + trip + "/" + year + "/" + user + "/";
    return View();
}
```

and here is a sample URL of how I'm trying to hit it:

```
http://localhost:31065/home/show/green/2013/hunt
```

neither of those methods in my global.asax are working.  Everything I've read would lead me to believe that this should work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the 404 saying it can't find exactly?

Comment: I added your first route and your controller action and that URL works just fine.  Is your `Show` view in the `Home` folder within the `Views` folder, e.g. `Views\Home\Show.cshtml`?

Comment: yes the show view is in there.  Interestingly if I just go to /home/show, the page comes up.  I've made sure that I've rebuilt the solution and it's still not working.

Comment: You're not using both those routes together are you?  Do you have your route defined before the default route?

Comment: doh!  It turns out the routing in my project is happening in a different file (different from global.asax), called reouteconfig.cs.  Go ahead and create an answer and I'll accept it as you got me thinking outside the box for this solution...thanks.

Comment: Excellent, glad that sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my `RouteConfig` that works with the URL `http://localhost:31065/home/show/green/2013/hunt`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Show",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{trip}/{year}/{user}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Show" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```